# The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dependencies, classpath

This issue occurs when updating the dependencies classpath from 
***'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'*** to ***'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'**

*project-level* **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

*app-level* **build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "org.company.com.flutter_app"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

***pubspec.yaml***

```
dependencies:
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
flutter_svg: ^0.12.0
printing: ^2.0.0
image: ^2.0.7
```

Comment: are you using any plugin? Android x Gradle build failure often occurs when you use a plugin which is not compatible with android x. also make sure you have updated your android studio.

Comment: Used dependencies::

  flutter_svg: ^0.12.0
  image: ^2.0.7

Comment: @jazzbpn, please share the error and also app/build.gradle file.

Comment: You could simply avoid androidX.. check this link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx

Answer (score 19):

add this in android/gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Ref: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: After adding the above lines to `android/gradle.properties` make sure to update the gradle dependencies in `app/build.gradle` such as:
```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    ...
```
Ref: http://blog.wafrat.com/flutter-androidx-migration/

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, after checking these 2 links:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

and [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedprogramclassmember). The only thing that worked for me was removing `minifyEnabled true` fom build.graddle.

Hope it help some one.

Comment: If you remove that line your code won't be obfuscated, you should fix by adding proguard rules

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are using a Flutter dependency which is not compatible to Androidx, Try to comment the recent dependency and re-run it, If it's work, Try to use the dependency that's compatible with Androidx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all assets are in use .

then `flutter pub get` then `flutter pub upgrade` then `flutter pup outdated`.