# I am unable to run my app on my android emulator from my flutter/android studio project. it happened after I added an image in the pubspec folder and

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\Emuesiri\Desktop\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Emuesiri\Desktop\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: check if you have any assets is not founded by pubspec.yaml maybe for typo you will get Waring for that after packages get

check AndroidX compatibilities in this Flutter app for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369997/the-gradle-failure-may-have-been-because-of-androidx-incompatibilities-in-this-f

Comment: Check where, sir?

Comment: Please also attach your pubspec.yaml file if you believe the error came from your pubspec.