# Error: Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: flutter

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 1

I have this problem on Android Studio.
Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Firstly I'd recommend adding the flutter tag to reach users with experience in that.

Please run flutter doctor -v and edit your answer to include the output of the console.

Comment: Have you added 'C:\flutter\bin' to your path variables, if so try running flutter doctor from AS terminal > flutter doctor see if it detects any errors

Comment: Probably it isn't Javascript. Java and Javascript are seperate languages.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140796/11675817

Answer (score 1):

Checking each of your .dart file if any file imports the unexpected module likes 'dart:js';
I remove the dart:js ,then the promble gone.
[it may be at the top of the .dart file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B5QX.png)

Answer (score 1):

1.Close Android Studio

2.Delete antivirus

3.Reinstall the stable version of flutter sdk.

link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install?gclid=Cj0KCQjwvLOTBhCJARIsACVldV07PdaqGdZITkLHIXr3rycWiK-o_pQkoy6-hePjYXXDPZEPlgBE5RIaAmX1EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

4.Open your project

5.Flutter clean

6.Flutter pub get

7.Finish

It worked for me!!!

Reason:
Some antiviruses think flutter files are viruses and eat them

Comment: "Delete antivirus" - I don't like that advice.

Comment: It worked for me.. its a holy fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. I had similar issues but was resolved after that