# Process 'command "flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been battling with this issue since yesterday after I upgraded my flutter and I don't know what is causing this issue. I have searched it from Google but I don't seem to find any answer so I need help.

The location of my Flutter SDK and the error is below.

```
Script 'C:\Users\src\Music\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\src\Music\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 20s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140796/11675817

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I once had a similar issue. I just deleted flutter and reinstalled the newest version directly by downloading the stable zip file from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: I have done the same, still not working

Answer (score 0):

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Please give the solution of this type of error.