# How to solve flutter.gradle and flutter.bat error?Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' && flutter.bat error

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue, I also get the same issue :-(

Comment: @PulsaraSandeepa checkout my answer. I Just found a solution to this issue.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140796/11675817

Answer (score 20):

The solution that worked for me was:

1. Delete `pubspec.lock` file
2. Do `flutter pub get`
3. Run the project

And it worked.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to get around this by running with null safety turned off. See [this article](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) for details.

```
 dart --no-sound-null-safety run
 flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this outdated but should help someone.

Yesterday I Just restarted my pc and got this issue. I tried to search for the solution to this problem but nothing works in my case.

**Solution**

Just delete your flutter folder (Flutter Source) and then reinstall it. Your problem will solve.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, the problem is from ur Gradle settings.
For me, when I got the error, the problem was from the app/build.gradle file. there, my minSdkVersion was set to 23, so I just changed it to 21 and the error was solved. I will suggest u check your targetSdkVersion is set to 29 and compileSdkVersion is 29. I hope this help you too

Comment: You have to set the targetSdkVersion to 30 because the Play Store won't allow you to upload any appbundle targeted with the version 29.

Answer (score 2):

- First `flutter clean` then `flutter run` worked for me. Ref - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75139. Thanks to https://github.com/darshankawar

Comment: @TonnyBaw this may or may not work for everyone as in the github also it worked for few people. So, maybe you can try something else mentioned above by other users.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I moved the project folder to D:, flutter clean, pub get and it runs

Answer (score 2):

(In my case this error occurred after I upgrade Android Sdk to 31)

Go to AndroidManifest.xml and Set this to all Activities with

```
android:exported=true
```

Answer (score 2):

if you build apk with --obfuscate, don't forget add a dot to head of your
--split-debug-info directory.

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/projectfolder/debug
```

to

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=./debug
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried flutter clean, reinstalling SDK. Nothing worked.
My folder name was not correct. It was `mvvm,provider test` I changed it to `mvvm_provider_test`. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened when I added a certain plugin. It turned out that the plugin required a minSdkVersion of 18. After I changed that, I did a `flutter clean` and after that, `flutter pub get`. So from this, I believe if you just added a recent plugin before you started facing this issue you look through the documentation of that plugin for installation info.

Also, after I did the above I had to restart my pc.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using flutter in command-line, just add -v which will run any flutter command in verbose mode. This should show you the origin of an error.

Like for me I was building with --split-debug-info and the folder I chose did not exist

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what worked for me was removing the `pubspec.lock` and then doing a  `flutter pub get` in my vscode command console, being in my project. Then modify the `android\app\build.gradle` file. inside the file I had `compileSdkVersion 30` and update to version 31, being as follows `compileSdkVersion 31`

Answer (score 0):

Download new Flutter SDK and update flutter path in your project,
And try again

Answer (score 0):

After i upgraded to Android Sdk 31, this came for me. What solved was the answer suggested by @Elias Fazel above but before doing that, i first needed to edit my gradle.properties file. Added the following line :-

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

This was suggested from here : [How to fix the ''module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module '' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67782975/how-to-fix-the-module-java-base-does-not-opens-java-io-to-unnamed-module)

After this, i added this line to activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml & then it worked.

```
android:exported=true
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in `Git`
I have shifted to another branch which was merged and that causes the issue . then
checkout from the `master` to `main` problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was in my pubspec.yaml file. I made some changes to it got this error commented out those changes and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's related with the Gradle, this issue comes when you have multiple Gradle versions in C:\Users\userName.gradle directory, the solution I made I deleted all directory files in .gradle directory, and restarted the IDE  again with default gradle version who comes when you try to create the project at the first time  (gradle-7.4-all.zip) this way works for me.

Answer (score 0):

did face the same issue
"flutter pub cache clean" - running this command solved my issue
hope this becomes helpful

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any solution so i did window again and all required software like flutter android studio etc.

and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrestled with this thing for some time. The issue is most likely due to a Gradle update. You need to update Gradle on your Flutter project as well.

You might also need to update you Target, Compile Version SDK and Kotlin version just to rule that out.

1. Go to android/app/build.gradle and update the Gradle classPath as below

*classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'*

2. Go to android/app/gradle-wrapper.properties

*distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip*

Once done, run flutter.

Battle won, but the war with Gradle continues, until next time.