# while using google sign in and getting this error

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: You can try to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136279/how-to-solve-flutter-gradle-and-flutter-bat-errorscript-c-src-flutter-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you have to do the following:

In the root folder of your app, from your terminal:

flutter clean

flutter pub get

restart your editor