# Errors running a flutter application on the android studio's virtual emulator, what does it mean?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Running the application I see these warnings.
What do they mean?

> 

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.

- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-2.2.1/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:45:41: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  String get packageRoot => io.Platform.packageRoot;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
- 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(28).cast();
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast().ref;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
- 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
- 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(20).cast().unpackString(128);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
- 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  ..addressOf.cast().elementAt(20).value = 0;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast().asTypedList(pinLength));
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
- 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  addressOf.cast().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:58:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:61:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:64:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:99:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:102:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:105:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.dart:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.dart:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:68: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:64: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
- 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
- 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.3.4/lib/src/colorpicker.dart:305:53: Error: The getter 'body2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body2'.
  Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2.copyWith(
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_colorpicker-0.3.4/lib/src/hsv_picker.dart:419:53: Error: The getter 'body1' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
- 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body1'.
  Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
  ^^^^^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class Utf16 extends Struct {
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class Utf8 extends Struct {
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class STATSTG extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class CLSID extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
  class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
  ^
  /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf();
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve flutter.gradle and flutter.bat error?Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter\_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' && flutter.bat error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136279/how-to-solve-flutter-gradle-and-flutter-bat-errorscript-c-src-flutter-package)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps

1. Delete `.idea` folder and `build` folder as well as `pubspec-lock` file.
2. run `flutter clean`
3. run `flutter pub get`