# After running flutter pub upgrade my app stops running

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I started getting this error immediately I ran **flutter pub upgrade**, I have tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136279/how-to-solve-flutter-gradle-and-flutter-bat-errorscript-c-src-flutter-package) but it is not working for me, I have also ran

- Flutter clean
- Flutter pub get
- Deleted and install new flutter

any help will be really appreciated
**NOTE** I'm using an M1 Pro MacBook.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: probaly you use package that not matched with required compileSdk version.

Comment: Yes that's what i thought i just don't know the particular package because i have a lot of packages in my application

Comment: can you show your package list and sdk version. maybe i also use the same package. and also your current compilesdk version

Comment: i have edited the question with the screenshot of my packages  also the compileSdkVersion is 32

Comment: in my case, i use compilesdkVersion 33, with latest firebase version.  maybe you can try to upgrare your firebase package.  fyi my fcm now is v - 13.0.3

Comment: okay let me try it then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248464/discussion-between-onyema-anthony-and-pmatatias).

Answer (score 0):

Yes its most probably you are using a package that is not yet compatible or does not match with required compileSdk version.
To identify which package is causing the issue, maybe you can try to revert your pubspec to when it was working and upgrade your packages one by one.
I'm also using M1 Macbook, so if you need further help, let me know.

Comment: I just reverted my pubspec to when it was working but it didn't fix it

Comment: Did you also upgrade you flutter version?

Comment: Can you try deleting your pubspec.lock, and press 'Pub Get' in your pubspec.yaml, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. from top menu bar select Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter clean
2. Open pubspec.yaml & execute pub get & run again your code

Comment: Thanks but i have done this things already and it didn't work

Comment: try some answers given in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930007/how-to-solve-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuilddebug

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your help, I have finally solved the error from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat)