# I'm trying to run the ambulance app in flutter and facing these errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm facing this error in flutter application. Please help me in resolving the error

> Launching lib\main.dart on SM J415F in debug mode...
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
> registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
> lib/services/auth.dart:16:18: Error: The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.
> - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
> ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.2.0/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onAuthStateChanged'.
> return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> ```
> lib/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart:25:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
>       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9:
> ```
>
> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> const Scaffold({
> ^^^^^^^^
>
> ```
> lib/screens/authenticate/register.dart:25:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
>       resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9:
> ```
>
> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> const Scaffold({
> ^^^^^^^^
>
> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * Where:
> Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
>
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> > Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3m 19s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
> Exited (sigterm)
> ```

This is the code of file register.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/services/auth.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/screens/authenticate/sign_in.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/screens/authenticate/authenticate.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/services/auth.dart';
//import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  Register({this.toggleView});
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  bool isEmailValid = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(children: [
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Text(
                "Welcome! \n\nCreate an new account",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    filled: true,
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[900]))),
                validator: (value) => value.contains('@') && value.contains('.')
                    ? null
                    : 'Enter a valid email',
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    filled: true,
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[900]))),
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ chars long' : null,
                obscureText: true,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    password = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[100])),
                  color: Colors.purple[300],
                  child: Text(
                    'Register',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      try {
                        dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailPassword(
                            email, password);
                      } catch (e) {
                        error = 'Please enter a valid email';
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[100])),
                  color: Colors.purple[300],
                  child: Text('Sign in to an existing account',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    widget.toggleView();
                  }),
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of file sign_in.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/screens/authenticate/register.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/screens/home/home.dart';
import 'package:my_app/services/auth.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  SignIn({this.toggleView});
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // text field states
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(children: [
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Text(
                "User Sign In \n",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 30,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    filled: true,
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[900]))),
                validator: (value) => value.contains('@') && value.contains('.')
                    ? null
                    : 'Enter a valid email',
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                    filled: true,
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[900]))),
                validator: (val) =>
                    val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ chars long' : null,
                obscureText: true,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    password = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[100])),
                  color: Colors.purple[300],
                  child: Text('Sign in', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      try {
                        dynamic result = await _auth.signInWithEmailPassword(
                            email, password);
                      } catch (e) {
                        error = 'Could not sign in with those credentials';
                        print(error);
                      }
                    }
                  }),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              RaisedButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple[100])),
                  color: Colors.purple[300],
                  child: Text('Create a new account',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    widget.toggleView();
                  }),
              Text(error)
            ])),

        /*child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Sign in as a Guest"),
            onPressed: () async {
              dynamic result = await _auth.signInAnon();
              print(result);
              if (result == null) {
                print('Error Signing in');
              } else {
                print('Signed In');
                return Home();
              }
            }),*/
      ),
    );
    return scaffold;
  }
}
```

This is the code from file auth.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/user.dart';
//import 'package:my_app/screens/home/home.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on FirebaseUser
  TheUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? TheUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<TheUser> get user {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map((User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
  }

  //Anonymous
  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
      //return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //sign iin Email and password
  Future signInWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email.trim(), password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // register
  Future registerWithEmailPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email.trim(), password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error Occured: ' + e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code from file main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/screens/wrapper.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:my_app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:my_app/models/user.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<TheUser>.value(
        value: AuthService().user, child: MaterialApp(home: Wrapper()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` is the parameter, it seems that it is typed wrong in your code.

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked. But other errors are still there.

Comment: I have added an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things seem to be amiss here.

1. You are using a deprecated parameter `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` of the scaffold. Change it to `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` instead.
2. You are using another deprecated api from `Firebase` which is `FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged`. You should now use it like this,

   ```
   _auth.authStateChanges().map((User user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` parameter of Scaffold was `deprecated` in v1.1.9

The `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` parameter should be used instead

Please refer [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/1-22-deprecations)

Comment: And regarding the `flutter.bat` error kindly refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat