# How to fix gradle error in flutter project

Tags: firebase, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am getting this gradle error when running flutter project:

I am using code from github for flutter pdf view and also using firebase for it.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);

                        ^^^^^^^^^

      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.

class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Plz help me I have got these gradle errors many time.
Thanks

Comment: @George yr wrong it had the problems with the old files, I deleted them now it works fine

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140796/11675817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the .idea folder , build folder and pubspec.lock file, then it will work just fine.