# Flutter debug error, FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

Why am I getting the following error? All of a sudden it started giving this error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Did you try deleting `pubspec.lock` file? If not, try it. Or try these steps

```
Go to pubspec.yaml file in android studio.
try doing “packages get”
and then build the project again.
```

or
follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66406390/16094734

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: hey, @imonursahin I updated the answer with a URL that takes you to another answer which is similar to your error. Try it out. Hope its works for you.

Comment: it didn't happen again and strangely i started getting this error in all my projects