# I want to be able to have multiple widgets in a page, it isn't working though. I want to have containers like the image below. It only allows me text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**This is the code below, please much appreciated if you can at least try. thank you |**
I am trying to create an app where I can have multiple widgets in one page. I want to make apps kind of like the image below here:

That I Want Widgets To Look Like or Similar To It

[image: 1]

This Is How My App Looks Like Blank

[image: img]

If you guys can help me figure out what I need to do that will be much appreciated beyond everything in existence. | Also, I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5efE6xobjg). But, as you all can observe he only has a string of text as "Hello", "CART", "MENUE", "SETTING", "FAVORITES", Which are all text strings. I want to make widgets inside this pages, like the first image. Please I been trying to figure this out for the past 4 and a half weeks and  I cant get to see how to make it possible.

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
final List<Widget> _options = [
  const _HomeScreenPage(),
  const _chatScreenPage(),
  const _locateScreenPage(),
  const _locationScreenPage(),
  const _profileScreenPage(),
];

int _currentIndex = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text(
      '               S|D',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 48,
        fontFamily: 'Subway',
      ),
    ),
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    foregroundColor: Colors.cyan,
  ),
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.black87,
    child: Center(
        child: Text(
          _options[_currentIndex],
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 40),
        ),
        ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.black54,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
    color: Colors.black,
    items: const <Widget>[
      Icon(
        Icons.home,
        color: Colors.cyan,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.people_sharp,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.my_location_sharp,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.car_repair,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.person_pin,
        color: Colors.cyan,
      ),
    ],
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    },
  ),
);
}
}

class _HomeScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
const _HomeScreenPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        flex: 7,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.cyan,
        ))
  ],
);
}
}

class _chatScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
const _chatScreenPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container();
}
}

class _locateScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
const _locateScreenPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container();
}
}

class _locationScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
const _locationScreenPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container();
}
}

class _profileScreenPage extends StatelessWidget {
const _profileScreenPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container();
}
}
```

Comment: Check a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IndexedStack widget inside your homePage build method

replace

```
  body: Container(
color: Colors.black87,
child: Center(
    child: Text(
      _options[_currentIndex],
      style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.cyanAccent,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 40),
    ),
    ),
),
```

to

```
   body: IndexedStack(
    children: _options,
    index: _currentIndex,
  ),
```