# that's error with shared_preferences package

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, mobile, sharedpreferences

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6rmR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Build Error: Process 'command 'E:\Flutter Apps\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat)

Comment: Do flutter clean, then do flutter pub get and then flutter run