# Flutter build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, gradle

Script 'C:\Users\Kevin Ojeda\Documents\development\sdks\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\Kevin Ojeda\Documents\development\sdks\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

So far I've tried most of the solutions suggested in this site from other users with similar errors to no avail.

I did check the flutter.bat file and apparently there are large chunks of it with errors. The errors are mostly single letters tho so I have no idea how to interpret that.

Comment: Does any answer from this question works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat

Comment: Did you try flutter clean and flutter pub get and removing the application from your device and try to run in again?

Comment: OMiShah yeah I tried all of them. None of them worked.
Md.Kamrul Amin. Tried that as well. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

usually the problem is due to different versions of flutter. you can check similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552962/flutter-build-error-process-command-e-flutter-apps-flutter-bin-flutter-bat)

Comment: How do I know if I'm using the correct version of flutter though?